# Eclipse-What is the root of a plugin project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am currently using a third party plugin to develop an Entity-Relationship Diagram graphically.

However, I am having some problems with classpaths.

I am giving the path of a jar file to the plugin project. However, during runtime, the plugin is throwing a `ClassDefNotFoundError`. I think this is because the plugin cannot find the jar file.

So, I intend to place the jar file in the plugin's root directory. However, I cannot find the root directory of the plugin. Where is the root directory of the plugin located?

Comment: If you want to use a jar in a plugin it must be part of the plugin (or another plugin), the plugin will not look at any other jars.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean to say.
I have some jar files which are stored in another Eclipse project. I am giving the path of those jar files to this plugin. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes. When a plugin is built it can only use code in plugins. It cannot access non-plugin jars (except via a class loader).

Comment: So how do I solve my problem? Do I copy the jar files into the plugin root?

Comment: You have to include the jars as part of the plugin. They have to be listed in the 'build.properties' and in 'Bundle-ClassPath' in the MANIFEST.MF

Comment: When I go in the build.properties file, and click on `add` to add a new jar, it doesn't show me any browse button to navigate to where I have my jar files on disk. What do I do now?

Comment: You have to include it in the plugin project

Comment: The path of my jar file is `D:\Workplace\SRS2ER\Stanford\edu\nlp\LexicalizedParser.jar`.
The `SRS2ER` is another eclipse project which does some work. 
How do I include it in the plugin project? That is exactly where I am getting stumped.